# Operational Amplifier multiplier

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

I have a question involving a couple problems in the following PDF: http://www.engr.colostate.edu/ECE103/FA13/homeworks/Homework6%20FA2013.pdf

For convenience, I'll also post them below.

As far as I understood, an inverting op amp would take the input voltage and multiply it by -(Ro/R1). So for instance, in #1 the output voltage would be 2 volts, correct?

However, what is the input voltage I am to multiply by in the case of #2, where the positive terminal is linked to a 5 volt power supply? Is it still 10 volts (v1) or is it now 5 volts (or something else)?

Problems:

[image: Image of PDF]

Comment: I like how they arbitrarily decided that dots indicating connections are optional...

Comment: Op amps multiply the difference between their two inputs. That's why an infinite-gain op amp acts as a comparator.

Comment: But isn't the difference between the two inputs supposed to be negligible? I apologize for my ignorance in this subject. I'm just trying to understand how to solve these problems.

Comment: The op amp will attempt to make it negligible. Current will flow, and voltages will result.

Comment: So in reference to my question, If I put a voltage source on the positive input of the op amp, will it change the voltage I am to multiply by to 5 volts (or something else), or will it remain at 10 volts? So will the output voltage be 10 volts or 20 volts or something else?

Comment: If the voltage at the non-inverting input is 5V, then what must the voltage at the inverting input be?

Comment: I would assume 5 volts, correct?

Comment: What then is the voltage across and current through the 100-ohm resistor?

Comment: Voltage would be +5 volts, and current would be 5/100 or 0.02 A

Comment: Where is this current coming from (Hint: not the op amp)?

Comment: The voltage source?

Comment: That's on one side. What's on the other?

Comment: The only thing on the other side of the op amp before the reference node is the resistor with the output voltage.

Comment: On the other side of the resistor we were discussing.

Comment: Well the other side of the resistor is joined with its parallel branch and then fed into the op amp's negative terminal.

Comment: On the other side of the 100-ohm resistor from the voltage source is the 200-ohm resistor. What is the voltage across this resistor?

Comment: Since none of the current should be diverted through the op amp, +10 volts.

Comment: Given that the voltage at the inverting input is 5V, and the voltage across the 200-ohm resistor is 10V, what is the voltage at the output of the op amp (keep in mind which way the current is flowing)?

Comment: Since we started with -10 and added 15, +5 volts, correct?

Comment: David, you were asking where to start.  Start with ideal OpAmp assumptions and Kirchhoff Current Law (KCL).  The rest is algebra.  Keep in mind that this board is not here to do your homework.  So far, you haven't demonstrated any effort to speak of.  You were only asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case, you are right. It's an inversor amplifier.

The second exercise has a differential amplifier. In mostly books, it has the next output:

$$v_{o}=v_{2}-v_{1}$$

However, it's a special case assuming equal resistors.

If you perform nodal analysis in your exercise, you will get:

$$v_{o}=\frac{[(200+100) \Omega]V_{2}-(200 \Omega)V_{1}}{100 \Omega}$$

Comment: So it should be 5 volts, correct?

Comment: How did you do that nodal analysis?

Comment: Remember it's a new configuration. I prefer to analyse the circuit. In the standard differential amplifier, all resistors are the same. This case is different.

Comment: Oh I get it. So the output voltage of the op-amp is +5, but Vo must be -5 volts in order to equal zero at the reference node.

Comment: @David what equation are you using to get \$v_{o}=+5V\$?

Comment: I'm not getting Vo = +5. I'm getting the output voltage of the op-amp to be +5. Since we start with V1 = -10 V, the inputs of the op-amp must be -5 V. This leaves -5 to go through the 200 Ohm branch. Then the 200 ohm resistor produces another +10 V, leaving us with +5 V at the output. Therefore, in order to equal zero at the reference node, Vo must be -5 V.

Comment: Ah ok, I get it ;)